# what is the difference between @local host and //localhost in getConnection() method

Tags: java, jdbc

why in **getConnection()** method,  localhost accept ***@localhost***  and it accept ***//localhost*** why and what is the difference between **@localhost** and **//localhost** .

i.e,

```
Connection 
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE",
"system","system");
```

Comment: The SID based URL syntax `@localhost:1521:XE` has been [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-6F729E4D-064B-4FD9-AE92-1BD44B8BE5EF) since Oracle 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the JDBC connection string depends on the database vendor or driver (apart from the `jdbc:` prefix and the requirement of having at least three separated-by-colons fields - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380071/jdbc-connection-string-syntax-and-anatomy)).

In the case of Oracle, and specifically its "thin" driver, there are [several syntaxes](https://www.dba-resources.com/oracle/jdbc-connection-strings-for-oracle-thin-driver/), depending on whether you use [the Service Name or the SID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid)

In short, if using Service Name you write

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host_name:port_number/service_name`

where `host_name` can be `localhost`.

If using SID you write  instead

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@host_name:port_number:sid_number`

Your example corresponds to this latter case.

Comment: The syntax with the SID is deprecated since Oracle 10. The [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-44572C63-10D2-478A-BB2E-ACF6674C59CC) doesn't even list it as a possibility any more.